# Спрятать блок при клике на ссылку на сайте Лендинг пейдж

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать вот такую опцию, чтобы при открытии меню с обзора на мобильном приложении нажимая на ссылку-якорь переход в раздел сайта, скрывалась боковая панель меню автоматически. Спасибо!!!

Вот коды css и html какие имею:

```css
    .hidden-menu {display:block;position:fixed;list-style:none;padding:15px;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;width:320px;background-color:#eee;height:100%;top:0;right:-320px;transition:right .2s;z-index:2;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
    .hidden-menu li {margin: 10px auto;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker {display:none;}
    .btn-menu {color:#0058B9;position:fixed;top:22px;right:22px;cursor:pointer;transition:right .23s;z-index:3;width:25px;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
    .btn-menu span {display:block;height:3px;background-color:#fff;margin:5px 0 0;transition:all .1s linear .23s;position:relative;}
    .btn-menu span.first {margin-top:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu {right:0px;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-menu {right:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.first {-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);top:8px;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.second {opacity:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.third {-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);top:-8px;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
    <label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
     <span class="first"></span>
     <span class="second"></span>
     <span class="third"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="hidden-menu">
    <li class="hi"><a href="#features">Особенности</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#show">Наши клиенты</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#stoimost">Цены</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#otzv">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#team">Команда</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#kontakt">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии по ссылке (`.hidden-menu a`) нам нужно нажать так-же на скрытый инпут (`#hmt`). Делается это так:

jQuery:

```
$('.hidden-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#hmt').click()
})
```

```js
$('.hidden-menu a').click(function(){
$('#hmt').click()
})
```

```css
body{background:#ccc}
.hidden-menu {display:block;position:fixed;list-style:none;padding:15px;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;width:320px;background-color:#eee;height:100%;top:0;right:-320px;transition:right .2s;z-index:2;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
    .hidden-menu li {margin: 10px auto;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker {display:none;}
    .btn-menu {color:#0058B9;position:fixed;top:22px;right:22px;cursor:pointer;transition:right .23s;z-index:3;width:25px;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
    .btn-menu span {display:block;height:3px;background-color:#fff;margin:5px 0 0;transition:all .1s linear .23s;position:relative;}
    .btn-menu span.first {margin-top:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu {right:0px;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-menu {right:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.first {-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);top:8px;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.second {opacity:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.third {-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);top:-8px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
    <label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
     <span class="first"></span>
     <span class="second"></span>
     <span class="third"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="hidden-menu">
    <li class="hi"><a href="#features">Особенности</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#show">Наши клиенты</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#stoimost">Цены</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#otzv">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#team">Команда</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#kontakt">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Чистый JavaScript:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".hidden-menu a"), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("hmt").click()
  });
});
```

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".hidden-menu a"), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("hmt").click()
  });
});
```

```css
body{background:#ccc}
.hidden-menu {display:block;position:fixed;list-style:none;padding:15px;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;width:320px;background-color:#eee;height:100%;top:0;right:-320px;transition:right .2s;z-index:2;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
    .hidden-menu li {margin: 10px auto;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker {display:none;}
    .btn-menu {color:#0058B9;position:fixed;top:22px;right:22px;cursor:pointer;transition:right .23s;z-index:3;width:25px;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
    .btn-menu span {display:block;height:3px;background-color:#fff;margin:5px 0 0;transition:all .1s linear .23s;position:relative;}
    .btn-menu span.first {margin-top:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu {right:0px;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-menu {right:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.first {-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);top:8px;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.second {opacity:0;}
    .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.third {-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);top:-8px;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
    <label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
     <span class="first"></span>
     <span class="second"></span>
     <span class="third"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="hidden-menu">
    <li class="hi"><a href="#features">Особенности</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#show">Наши клиенты</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#stoimost">Цены</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#otzv">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#team">Команда</a></li>
    <li class="hi"><a href="#kontakt">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ..... ТО ЧТО НАДО !!!!

Comment: @Алексей Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию. 

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при клике вне блока он закрывался?